# How to bulk convert Base64 to images in an Excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, image-conversion, base64, uri

I have an excel file with 500 rows of image URIs in Base64 (as you can see in the image). I need to convert them to images and download them to my computer. Is there a website/tool/code that can do that?

There are some website like [this](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter), but none does the batch conversion only single image.

EDIT 1: 
[Here's an example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17FOTGkwSRlB2jLQZt0NOFmXpxg7DhPKyM7wNK2Efcp8/edit?usp=sharing) of three image URIs in my excel file:

Appreciate your help.

[image: Fugly screen shot of Excel]

Comment: It's not hard to write a program of your own, but the screen shot doesn't provide enough detail to reveal exactly what's in your spreadsheet (and friends don't let friends use spreadsheets for this anyway). If you can show a few lines of actual text, it should not be hard for someone with basic Python or Javascript skills to whip something up for you.

Comment: The file is actually a website scraped output that fetched the image URLs like that in an Excel format. and the whole text in each cell would be too long and too mumbo jumbo to show.

Comment: Still, transcribing stuff from a screen shot is painful. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors ... But here: https://ideone.com/dKPiVz (untested, because you didn't post anything to test it with).

Comment: @tripleee Added a file in the edit as you recommended.

Comment: I already linked to a solution for text files. If you insist on providing the input as a spreadsheet I wish you good luck and lots of patience (though it's certainly possible and probably easy with the Python `docx` module).

Comment: Actually I'm guessing that the download produced a CSV file, which already *is* text. You just have to override the default application to not let the OS open it in Excel.

Comment: (Cursing that particular OS is optional, but standard prooedure.)

Comment: @tripleee thanks a ton for your solution. It worked perfect. I tried to do it with text file, copying excel rows in it and it worked. However, you had a typo in your code that I'm sure you can find it easily. 
I never coded Python but I tried giving it a shot to input excel file but I was unsuccessful. I'd be grateful if you could correct it for me. 
Here's my code:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WKo-VElXradvqYsePDf4u17xYxy0vU16/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You mean the semicolon instead of colon in the RFC 2397 identifier? Yeah, that's what happens when we have to work from screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not afraid of running a Python script, here's a quick one.

Pass in a text file where there's one base64 image per line.
This will write out a sequence of images, like `image0001.png`, `image0002.png`, ...

```
import fileinput
import base64

for index, line in enumerate(fileinput.input(), 1):
  if line.startswith('data:image/png;base64,'):
    with open('image{0:04}.png'.format(index), 'wb') as png:
       line = line.strip()
       png.write(base64.b64decode(line[22:] + '===='))
```

Save this into a file like `decode.py`, then run it with

```
python3 decode.py input.txt
```

If your input file is CSV with a single column, that's a text file, too, so you should be able to use that directly (though CSV might have quoting you need to trim off). If you really have to accept the input in a proper Excel spreadsheet, exporting that to CSV is a manual process which is one good reason to avoid Excel if you can.

Based on your comment, here is an attempt to use the `xlrd` module to read Excel directly, but I (thankfully) have nothing to test it on.

```
import base64
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("images.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")

for idx in range(1, worksheet.nrows+1):
    excel_data = worksheet.cell(idx-1,0).value
    if excel_data.startswith('data:image/png;base64,'):
        with open('image{0:04}.png'.format(idx), 'wb') as png:
            png.write(base64.b64decode(excel_data.strip()[22:] + '===='))
```

Your attempt was using the base64 data `excel_data` instead of the index in the the argument to `open` which specifies the file name. `idx` runs from 1 to the number of the final row of data.

**Addendum:**
Some of the data seems to be erroneous. I managed to extract your pictures with the following hack, but I'm not sure if it's actually producing correct output -- this seemed to work for the images I tried, but it could introduce corruption because I am simply dropping the last base64 character.

```
import fileinput
import base64
import binascii

for index, line in enumerate(fileinput.input(), 1):
  if line.startswith('data:image/png;base64,'):
    with open('image{0:04}.png'.format(index), 'wb') as png:
       line = line.strip()[22:]
       try:
         decoded = base64.b64decode(line + '====')
       except binascii.Error:
         decoded = base64.b64decode(line[0:-1] + '====')
       png.write(decoded)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works a treat but I get this error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "E:\decode.py", line 11, in <module>
    png.write(base64.b64decode(excel_data.strip()[22:]))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\base64.py", line 78, in b64decode
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: Incorrect padding

I get that for many of the URIs. If their URIs aren't corrupt, what would be the problem? 
Here is a list of a few URIs that don't work and the code stops when it gets to them. 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q9qRwpXveMihiqEah559VYWYH6thlA0-qROy3AtOZLY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Base64 requires input to be an even multiple of 4 bytes long. I'm guessing the problematic data needs to have padding added. I'll update the answer with a quick fix.

Comment: I'm really not in a place where I can open a spreadsheet. It should not be hard to find the link to export your files as text.

Comment: I tried your codes both for text as well as excel.I'm still getting the same error. I'm temporarily sharing [the link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UqEKKdzKkX8Qp84a_8M5E7IGeY-RmPoV/view?usp=sharing) to the main excel file with all the image URIs in it for you to take a look.

Comment: I found an online converter: https://s12.aconvert.com/convert/p3r68-cdx67/adnp5-2t24y.txt

Comment: Here's the [CSV](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RtZK5vzNbmcnlvPuoLkyNQnsoO-c83du/view?usp=sharing)
and here's the [Text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LvY6st7RaaAxi0KiaTWGZMJlVA_5Xn-Q/view?usp=sharing). I've opened them to edit.

Comment: The error seems to be related to https://bugs.python.org/issue34736 but I don't see any invalid base64 characters on line 5, for example. The length of the padding actually doesn't seem to matter, as long as there is enough of it; you could just add `"===="` to the end of everything.

Comment: See also now https://stackoverflow.com/a/58705456/874188

Answer (score 1):

Python example from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214190/how-to-convert-base64-string-to-image):

```
import base64
imgdata = base64.b64decode(imgstring)
filename = 'some_image.jpg'
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(imgdata)
```

To import an Excel file, you can use `xlrd`. [Stack Overflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169325/read-excel-file-in-python).

Comment: This does it for a single image string. I need to do a back conversion getting the URIs from an excel sheet. (See Edit 1 in the question).

Comment: If you don't know any Python at all, this is going to be hard. If you do, I hoped you would understand that the first part of the code converts the base64 string, and the second part about importing an excel file is what would allow you to parse the Excel file: you would then iterate over each row of the file imported with the "single image code" in a for loop.