# Bulk convert image-data URIs to images

Tags: windows-10, images, image-processing, image-conversion, base64

I have a text file of 391 image-data URIs, one on each line. I need to batch-convert them all to images, named according to their sequence (i.e. `image001.png`, `image002.png` or similar). 
What do people suggest?

Windows 10 operating system. Also MacOS.

Comment: What tools do you have available? What _operating systems_ do you have availabe?

Comment: Windows 10 operating system. Also MacOS. Not sure what you mean by tools?

Answer (score 0):

Found from another question - see [here](https://superuser.com/a/1498884/1139307)
This should work as it is one per line.

---

If you are not afraid of running a Python script, here's a quick one.

Pass in a text file where there's one base64 image per line.
This will write out a sequence of images, like `image0001.png`, `image0002.png`, ...

```
import fileinput
import base64

for index, line in enumerate(fileinput.input(), 1):
  if line.startswith('data:image/png;base64,'):
    with open('image{0:04}.png'.format(index), 'wb') as png:
       line = line.strip()
       png.write(base64.b64decode(line[22:] + '===='))
```

Save this into a file like `decode.py`, then run it with

```
python3 decode.py input.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for this - do I need anything to run Python or will it just work?

Comment: You will need Python installed - you can grab it [here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.1/python-3.8.1.exe)

Comment: @Gabriel Once you have it installed, you can run it in CMD either using `python3 (name of script.py) (name of text file.txt)` or `python (name of script.py) (name of text file.txt)` you may need to [add Python to your Windows path](https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/)